# sudo emacs doesn't read my elpa packages

Tags: centos, sudo, emacs

Here is my problem on a server running CentOS 7 with emacs 24.3.1.:

- When I run `sudo emacs <protected_file>` on a file that I don't have write permissions, emacs doesn't read my .emacs file, nor does
  it recognize the commands defined in .emacs.d/elpa/.
- When I run `sudo emacs -u myuserid <protected_file>` on that file, emacs reads my .emacs file but still doesn't know about my elpa packages.
- When I run `emacs <protected_file>`, it reads .emacs and knows about
  .emacs.d/elpa packages. (But the file is opened in read-only mode, of
  course.)
- When I run `sudo emacs <myfile>` on a file I have write permission on, emacs doesn't read my .emacs file, nor does
  it recognize the commands defined in .emacs.d/elpa/.
- `emacs <myfile>` works as expected.

However, on the server that I copied my home directory from, which runs CentOS 6 with emacs 23.1.1, everything works fine. `sudo emacs <protected_file>` reads .emacs and it recognizes the commands within .emacs.d/elpa/.

I've verified that the file and directory permissions in my home directory are identical on both servers.

Since both the OS level and the emacs level are different, it seems like it could be either `sudo` or `emacs` where the problem lies (or in the way the systems people configured the new server).

Any ideas about this odd behavior?

**UPDATE**: Original post stated in bullet 4 that `sudo emacs <myfile>` worked as expected. This wasn't true, and I've amended that above.

Comment: Your problem is that sudo , depending on how it is configured, does NOT use your user's environmental variables, it uses root's. So ~ is /root so you need to put the .emacs stuff you want in /roor/.emacs (I go best) and configure root's path, or use the full path to files rather than ~ or . Or , imo less preferable, configure sudo to use your user environmental variables  . See man sudo for details

Comment: Why `sudo emacs` at all? `sudoedit` is far better, since it doesn't require emacs itself to run as root

Comment: The combination of the first and fourth bullet points is very, very strange.

Comment: @MichaelHomer you are correct; I was mistaken. Actual behavior is consistent with bullet 1. I've edited the original post.

Comment: @Fox `sudoedit` worked just fine! Your comment appears to have solved my problem ($EDITOR is emacs). Feel free to post as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that when running your editor via `sudo`, it will use root's environment instead of your own. You could just configure the editor the same way for root as for your normal user, but obviously this doesn't extend well to systems where more than one person has `sudo` access.

The simplest solution, then, is to not run the editor under `sudo`. Just copy the original file, modify the copy, and copy it back over the original. Here, only the copy operations may need escalated privileges. On many systems, you can use this approach with

```
$ sudoedit /path/to/file
```

This will run `$SUDO_EDITOR`, `$VISUAL`, or `$EDITOR` (checked in that order) with standard privileges on a temporary copy of the target file and commit the changes to the original after the editor exits.

If your editor is set to `emacsclient` instead of just `emacs`, and you have an open emacs in server mode, you only have to close the buffer (not emacs as a whole) to commit the changes.